# How to calculate the weights of logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I want to use logistic regression for a machine learning problem. The formula this algorithm is P(y=1)=1/(1+ e^(-(b0+ b1 x1+b2 x2+⋯+bn xn))). How do you calculate the b0, b1,...,bn?

[image]

When this table is the training set, what are b0, b1 and b2 in the formula? And how do you calculate that?

Is the predicted class of a new object 0 when p(y=0) > p(y=1)?

Answer (score 0):

A very short answer would be that you usually define a [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) in terms  of your model, and then set the weights so that the resulting likelihood functinon (one usually uses log-likelihood) is maximized. See 
[When is logistic regression solved in closed form?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/949/when-is-logistic-regression-solved-in-closed-form)
.